# "python: command not found" on Oracle Linux 8

Tags: python, python3, oracle

I have previous had no problem building a mirror server with Oracle Linux 7. I have followed the same steps registering the server, adding subscriptions. When I later run `./uln-yum-mirror` script I immediately get an output saying `python: command not found`.

I realized I hadn't installed python, so I did, installing python38.

However again after running `uln-yum-mirror` I get same `python: command not found` message.

Scratching my head as I am bit out of ideas.

I have attempted adding `alias python='python38'` to `~/.bashrc`  but that has made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases that you set in your interactive shell never carry over into scripts that you execute.

On Oracle Linux 8, to make `python38` the default Python interpreter, you would first install Python 3.8 using

```bsh
sudo dnf module install python38
```

and then make `python38` the system's default Python interpreter using

```bsh
sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python38
```

See also the official Oracle Linux 8 documentation about [Installing Python](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/python/installing-python.html).

See also the [About Python](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/python/about-python.html) section in the same document. It mentions the fact that `python` no longer is aliased by default and that Python 2 is unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

The uln-yum-mirror script in /usr/bin has a line:

```
python  -c
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
python3 -c
```